What is the purpose of the pipe inside the double jar juice dispenser?
Here is the picture:

What is the purpose of the pipe inside the double jar juice dispenser?

That is the spray tube (or, on some imports, "mixing pole.") There's a pump that forces the contents through the tube to ensure drinks are consistent.
The Crathco beverage dispenser has this advice: "Most beverages can be sprayed. It is best not to spray iced tea, iced coffee, natural juices, or beverages that foam (whipped drinks). A special agitator plate is used in place of a pump cover and spray tube to promote circulation."

Pretty sure it's for pumping juice back up to the top so that the product remains mixed, and refrigerated, with the refrigeration being carried out in the base.
The overall design is "eyecatching" (so customers will see it as a juice dispenser) but not too thermally efficient, so presumably all those vents on the side are to support a refrigeration unit to keep the juice sufficiently cold to leave out safely. Without pumping the juice would stratify and the top would be too warm even if the bottom was quite cold. Note that the pipes in both chambers are full, even though the overall level is lower, so product must be getting pumped up there, and it makes thermal sense that it would be.
